# Select inside math function

Tags: mysql, sql, math

This is most likely a beginner's question in SQL. Is it possible to use a select within a math expression?

For example, I have two tables:
- table A with a column named id (primary key) and another column named val_A
- table B with a column named id (primary key) and another column named val_B

I want to do something like:

```
select ((select val_A from A where id = 1) +
    (select val_B from B where id = 1)) as final_sum;
```

I'm using MySQL and it is throwing errors. I'm assuming that this is because the result of a select is a set and I want the numeric value of val_A and val_B to be make the sum.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example works just fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dadc1/1

Comment: what's the error, because that syntax SHOULD work, assuming the subselects only return a single row/field each.

Comment: Now you puzzled me... It is not working for me here... :x

Comment: "You have a syntax error near ((select val_A ..."

Comment: Please post some information about A and B tables and uniqueness of `id` there.

Comment: @Sagito . . . If you have a syntax error as `((select val_A`, are you sure that you are including the preceding `select` in the statement when you execute it?

Comment: Yes, the SQL query is just the same as the one from @mellamokbtheWise and it doesn't seem to work...

The actual query I need is obviously different from this testing one, but neither seem to work... Could it be from this specific version of MySQL?

Comment: @Sagito . . . I doubt it is the version of MySQL.  This is standard SQL and MySQL 4.1 documentation explicitly says this is allowed (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/scalar-subqueries.html) and that version stopped being current many years ago.

Comment: You are right, of course... :/ But then, I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: My exact query is working on a different database in a different server... So... I have no idea what is happening...

Comment: @Sagito: How are you running the query?  From some sort of client program?  Could it be munging the query before it sends it to the server?  Try doing it directly using the command-line [`mysql` client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).

Comment: Well, I'm using the SQL panel from PHPMyAdmin... It is on a webhosting server, so unfortunately I don't have access to the console... :/

Answer (score 4):

The query that you have:

```
select ((select val_A from A where id = 1) +
        (select val_B from B where id = 1)
       ) as final_sum
```

is correctly formed SQL in MySQL (assuming that the table and columns exist).

However, it assumes that each subquery only returns one row.  If not, you can force it using `limit` or a function like `min()` or `max()`:

```
select ((select val_A from A where id = 1 limit 1) +
        (select max(val_B) from B where id = 1)
       ) as final_sum
```

Or, possibly, you are trying to get the sum of all the rows with id = 1 in both tables:

```
select ((select sum(val_A) from A where id = 1) +
        (select sum(val_B) from B where id = 1)
       ) as final_sum
```

Comment: I tried using max to see it it would work, but it threw the same errors... Either I'm being very stupid here (and don't see an obvious error) or this version of MySQL is broken... :/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, but a more proper query format would be:

```
SELECT (a.val_a + b.val_b) as final_sum
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 1
```

Comment: . . Although this *might* be what the questioner wants, it is not clear what to do in the case where there are duplicates between the tables (which might be part of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working, but you could try something like:

```
select (val_A + val_B) as final_sum from A,B where A.id=1 and B.id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Break down and test your query

select 1+1

so your statement is just without the select. This would run -

```
select ((select sum(val_A) from A where id = 1) +
(select sum(val_B) from B where id = 1)) as final_sum;
```

Comment: It will run only if both A and B tables have **one and only one** row with `id = 1`.

Comment: Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68d41/1) of the error you get when there is more than 1

Comment: @Pradyut Bhattacharya - While it will run now, there's no clear evidence that OP wanted it this way.

Comment: @PM77-1 please make yourself clear while you are replying. Everybody knows that OP is "may be" looking for something else...

Comment: I tried using MAX instead of sum but both crash... Also, I'm pretty sure that it only has one row, because I'm referring directly to the primary key